# Problems using ProcessBuilder with Java

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, processbuilder

Im trying to make a few .bat files run from a folder, getting an error which only the first bat runs, the others are ignored.

```
 final String direct = "FOLDER";

        File[] archives ;
        File diretorio = new File(direct);
        archives = diretorio.listFiles();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < archives.length; i++) {
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(archives[i].getPath());
                Process p = pb.start();
                
             //Only for printing the commands 
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String trace = null;
                while ((trace = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(trace);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post and include your troubleshooting steps? For example, does `reader.readLine()` never return null and that's why your program never tries to start the second one?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are actually dealing with a `.bat` batch file.
2. Be sure to close your reader when done with it so as to release the resources.
3. Destroy the Process when done with it so as to release the resources.

This should work:

```
File[] archives;
File diretorio = new File(direct);
archives = diretorio.listFiles();

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < archives.length; i++) {
        // Is it a .bat file
        String fileName = archives[i].getName();
        if (!fileName.contains(".")
                || !fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")).equalsIgnoreCase(".bat")) {
            // No...
            continue;
        }
        if (archives[i].isFile() && archives[i].canExecute()) {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", archives[i].getPath());
            Process p = pb.start();

            //Only for printing the commands
            // 'Try With Resources' used here to auto-close reader.
            try (java.io.BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
                String trace = null;
                while ((trace = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(trace);
                }
            }
            p.waitFor();
            p.destroy(); // In case of abnormal process termination though 'waitFor()'.
        }
    }
}
catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The code has been updated based on valid comments. **Process#waitFor()** is used in this updated code.

In the Windows OS, batch files are run though the Windows Command Processor (Command Prompt) but can be run through Windows File Association if let's say the batch file is double-click upon within the Windows File Explorer.

If association is available then the previous version of code should work

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(archives[i].getPath());
```

however sometimes It’s possible that the association for .bat files has been inadvertently associated with a text editor, or the settings have been tampered with in the registry. Once you set a file association for .bat files using the **Open With** dialog or default programs, there is apparently no way to revert to the default setting using the user interface. The only way to fix this is by changing the settings in the registry. You can do that by following these steps:

**Before proceeding, create a System Restore point as a safety measure. Incorrect modification of the Windows registry can cause serious problems.**

1. Open Notepad or your favorite text editor.
2. Copy the following lines and paste it into Notepad:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bat]
@="batfile"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell]
@=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat]
```

3. Save the file with any name having the **.reg** extension, say
   **BAT_File_Association.reg**
4. Double-click **BAT_File_Association.reg** to apply the configuration
   into the registry. Click <kbd>Yes</kbd> when prompted for
   confirmation.

You’ve now fixed the batch file association settings. Batch files should now execute correctly when double-clicked. You can read more about this [here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/bat-files-do-not-run-when-double-clicked-fix-association/).

In any case, the updated code above will now run the batch files though the Command Processor (cmd.exe) and again...should work. Because my system has **.bat** file association, either way works for me.

To make sure you're not having an issue with your batch files, add an echo to the top of each .bat file, for example:

```
@echo:Batch File 1
... the rest of batch file code ...
```

As each bat file is run you should see in your console window:

```
Batch File 1
Batch File 2
Batch File 3
etc
```

Comment: Using waitFor(timeout) is better than destroy() - this allows the process to end normally and to check the exit status before killing it.

Comment: @that-other-guy I tried to run without the while but It keeps only running the 1st (and for some reason, dont run all of it)

Comment: @DevilsHnd I tried to run this code, It identifies the .bat files but wont run any

Answer (score 0):

@DevilsHnd code works great!
The problem was with the .bat files with "pause" command.

Comment: Yup...that will do it all right. This should have been a comment instead of an answer by the way.  :/